# "orientation|keyboardHidden" not calling onConfigurationChanged

Tags: android, android-configchanges

I want to know when the keyboard is closed, so I'm using `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"`.  I have to override the method
 `onConfigurationChanged`, but nothing seems to happen.  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

watching the date , possibly you have a solution for your question, otherwise:

Here is the same response i made to another question related : [Is there a way to tell if the soft-keyboard is shown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457486/android-is-there-a-way-to-tell-if-the-softkeyboard-is-shown/5457919#5457919)

but i copy a portion of the response here to avoid dead links:

Here is a specific **sample**:

Check for better understanding http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Code from docs:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    // Checks whether a hardware keyboard is available
    if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard visible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard hidden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: softKeyboard show/hide never trigger onConfigurationChanged()

Answer (score 0):

Have you added `super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);` in the overridden method?