# Is there a way to tell if the soft-keyboard is shown?

Tags: android

is there a way to tell if the softkeyboard is shown in an activity or not?

I tried

```
InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager) 
getSystemService(getApplicationContext().INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
manager.isActive(v)
```

but **isActive** returns false only before the first time the keyboard is shown, but if the kb appears and then dismissed, **isActive** returns true also.

so is there any other method to check for this issue.

thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to this [POST](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/1c3291f15ed9c044/479f6233b27c5e30?pli=1)

You cannot detect if soft keyboard is shown or not, but you can indirectly know that a soft key board is shown by knowing that the `View` of your activity is resized.

Imagine you have a `ListView` and at the bottom an `EditText`, you want to go to the bottom of the list when a soft keyboard is shown after user clicks the EditText.

You need to implement a subclass of `ListView`, then use it in your `ListActivity` or `Activity` or `View`.

```
public class ThreadView extends ListView {

    public ThreadView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int xNew, int yNew, int xOld, int yOld) {
        super.onSizeChanged(xNew, yNew, xOld, yOld);

        if (yOld > yNew) {
            setSelection(((ListAdapter) getAdapter()).getCount() - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

PS. "check Configuration Changes" only works for hand keyboard.

Comment: I believe this is the only solution to this issue

Comment: This is the way to go, at least on Android 2.2 and to date.  It's a real pain that there is no API for detecting a soft keyboard (and for that matter, getting a handle on its slide up animation). Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Why did I see this only just now?! Spent a lot of time trying to use onMeasure, onLayoutChange, and so on and so forth.. And this is the only solution that worked. The simplest too! Thanks a lot Doraemon, oh I mean, @DiveInto. :p

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day. Stuck on this one for hours in creating chat Application using recyclerView.

Answer (score 4):

You can detect the state AND coordinates of the software keyboard, using `dumpsys` shell command.

Because dumpsys requires `permission.android.DUMP`, which is a system application permission, you have two options: 1. use a rooted device to grant this permission. 2. override the problem using `adb` as described in my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24104993/1609201).

Now, run the following command: `dumpsys window InputMethod | grep "mHasSurface"` to get the data you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

This is my idea. It is untested.

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);   

        // Checks whether a keyboard is available which is not hard keyboard
        if ((newConfig.keyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO)&&(newConfig.keyboardHidden != Configuration.KEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "soft keyboard visible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (newConfig.keyboardHidden == Configuration.KEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "soft keyboard hidden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Please check *Configuration Changes* for your Activity

This for your **AndroidManifest.xml**

and this for your *Activity* class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration)

You will need to @Override the public method **onConfigurationChanged**(android.content.res.Configuration) of your Activity to be able to handle, for example, these values:
 **hardKeyboardHidden**,
 **keyboard**,
 **keyboardHidden**

For all possible values check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html

You will see there something like this:

```
HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO   
HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_UNDEFINED    
HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES  
KEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO   
KEYBOARDHIDDEN_UNDEFINED    
KEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES  
KEYBOARD_12KEY  
KEYBOARD_NOKEYS 
KEYBOARD_QWERTY 
KEYBOARD_UNDEFINED
```

Also there you will be able to read something like this:

```
public int  hardKeyboardHidden // A flag indicating whether the hard keyboard 
                               // has been hidden.
public int  keyboard    The kind of keyboard attached to the device.
public int  keyboardHidden  A flag indicating whether any keyboard is available.
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is a specific **example** of what I´m talking about:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

```
    
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    // Checks whether a hardware keyboard is available
    if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard visible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == 
          Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard hidden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response, but it did not capture any change when the kb appeared or disappeared

Comment: Hi, you should search and example to see that when on your manifest you set android:configChanges="keyboardHidden" this will trigger the onConfigurationChanged method in any Activity you call. If you override the method you can pass new values for your activity or you can fetch current ones. I mean, that using this you can make your application listen for events like keyboard visibility changes and handle them within your Activity.

Comment: I just updated the response to add a sample coming from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html you will see there a better information on "Handling the Configuration Change Yourself"

Comment: Thanks yeradis, I'll check and tell you later

Comment: @yeradis configChanges only works for hard keyboard and orientation change,it won't work for soft keyboard

Comment: in that sample, YES but what about if you replace hardKeyBoardHidden by keyboardHidden, public int  keyboardHidden  A flag indicating whether ANY keyboard is available.

Comment: Thanks guys for response, but the event is not fired unless I specify orientation as a parameter of config changes, which I don't want to cause my entire application has orientation set to portrait (not changed)

Comment: I also tried the above approach (in Android 2.2), and the soft keyboard does not cause keyboard or keyboardHidden configuration events to fire.