# measure and call back change of screen size in android

Tags: android, keyboard, screen

i am new in android development. i have some difficulty about android screen size.

1 ) how to get my current application windows size .

```
ex: height = h px, width = w px
```

2 ) how to call back when windows size change. like when keyboard open then window size change but how to measure how change where is call back function.

```
ex: height = ( h - keyboardHeight ) px
    height = ( w - keyboardWidth ) px
```

1 . [first image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz9y_TjYqDl8d3V5T2ZQUHZ0SEE/view?usp=sharing) ( find red background size)

2 . [second image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz9y_TjYqDl8X0NDWXJLSC0tMm8/view?usp=sharing) ( open keyboard find and call back of red background size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels` x `getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels`
2. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5473245/517381